# Volume mute and unmute button getting pressed frequently

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, hardware

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo laptop. Since the laptop was almost 4 years old, one of my volume mute/unmute button got damaged and the relevant key press/release event got triggered automatically.

[image]

[image]

Since this action happens frequently, it causes terminal stuck until it gets stopped by its own. So I can't type any commands on the terminal during that specific time. This problem is killing me a lot.

I have tried some solutions like disabling the relevant keycode through `xmodmap`,

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 113='
xmodmap -e 'keycode 113=NoSymbol'
```

Still it's not working for me.. Later the same issue happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For me the this solution worked well:

`xmodmap -e 'keycode 121 = 0x0000'`

To find the proper keycode the xev utility can be used:

`xev`